# id parameter of Auth return an error -Laravel API

Tags: laravel, jwt, laravel-8, rest

This is an API to upload files. In this, admin as well as other users can upload files. so, i need to find the person who is uploading it and want to store it to the column `uploadedBy`. when tried with the below code , i get the error `Trying to get property 'id' of non-object` . I'm not ssure whether i can get the id like this. Pls help me with ur suggestions.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Files;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class FileController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
       $this->middleware('auth:api');
    }
    public function upload(Request $req)
    {
        $file=$req->file('file_name');
        $dataToInsert = array();
        $filePath= uniqid().'-'.now()->timestamp;
        $dataToInsert['FilePath'] = $filePath;
        $dataToInsert['uploadedBy'] = Auth::user()->id;
        $dataToInsert['Userid'] = $req->bearerToken();
        Files::create($dataToInsert);
    }
}
```

[image]

EDIT: Added the middleware . Now the error is that API simply shows the msg `unauthenticated`.

Comment: since `Auth::user()->id;` triggers an error, the user is not authenticated.

Comment: something is not working in the authentification hense the `unauthenticated`, we cant help you more with the info we have. here is some leads: Try with a new token (maybe it expired). If you have another API routes that works, check how it is done (maybe you have another auth for API like jwt-auth from tymon). Check your midleware class (if you have modified them)

Answer (score 1):

You should put your route on `auth` middleware, this route can be accessed after authenticated only, so that you can get user info by `auth()->user()`.

To access `id` only, just `auth()->id()`, this can return `null` if the application is not authenticated.
Please note that you pass gate name in `auth()` helper, eg: `auth('api')->id()`.

Answer (score -1):

You can get the id of the authenticated user by `auth()->id()`
Edit: You need to be logged in first, or it will throw an error

Comment: that's what he tried and that is what triggers the error

Comment: means he is not logged in yet

Comment: No it doesnt mean that. He asked `How to access id parameter of Auth` and the answer tells how to access it